# roscpp get a list of all namespaces

Tags: c++, namespaces, ros

I have looked around and couldn't find a way to get a list of currently running namespaces in a ROS environment using roscpp.

There seem to be tools to get the name of the current node namespace. But is there a clean way to get a list of **all** namespaces?

So far I came up with all sorts of sneaky ways to get it done, but I am curious to learn a real, proper way to do it, if there is one.

Comment: for what do you need the namespaces...wouldn't it be enough to get a node list ?

Comment: I would like to have separate external code pieces running for different namespaces. Node list does not provide a clear indication of the used namespaces.

Comment: sorry can't help with that...namespace listing seems to be more a c++ problem, maybe you ask for that on stackoverflow